# how do I use String.delete to remove '<em>' from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm sure I can do this with a regex, but I can't find any explanation for this behavior using just normal `delete!`:

```
#1.9.2
>> "helllom<em>".delete!"<em>"  
=> "hlllo"
```

[The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) don't have anything to say about this. Seems to me that it's treating `'<em>'` as a set. Where is this documented?

Edit: in my defense I was looking for special treatment of < and > in the docs under delete. Didn't see anything about it and tried google, which also didn't have anything to say about that -- because it doesn't exist.

Comment: On second thought you're correct that your question isn't a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523884/using-regular-expression-in-ruby/7523906) (though the title makes them seem slightly more different than they really are). What I was remembering about it was that, despite the question being framed in terms of regexes, the poster of that question made basically the same mistake about `delete` as you did.

Comment: @JohnFlatness Ok. Seems I'm not the only one who got turned around by this. I'd expect a method that deletes any character in a set to take in a set as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#delete` is one of those unfortunate methods that is difficult to explain (I have no idea what the use case is). In practice, I've always used gsub with an empty string as the second argument.

```
'helllom<em>'.gsub '<em>', '' # => "helllom"
```

Note that `String#gsub!` also has weirdness such that you should not depend on its return value, it will return `nil` if it does not alter the string, so it is best to use `gsub` if you depend on the return value, or if you want to mutate the string, then use `gsub!` but and don't use anything else on that line.

Comment: Actually I found a use case for it shortly after reading it. I have strings that are coming in that have garbage utf8 chars in them from time to time. So I can delete all those in one .delete call instead of 5-8 gsub calls. The readability of that line of code is pretty terrible though. It's very awkward in comparison to the normal readability of Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use String#delete to remove substrings.

Check the [API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete). It removes all the characters from given parameters from the given string.

I your case it removes all occurrences of `e`, `m`, `<` and `>`.

Comment: Crap you're right, I didn't see that "intersection of arguments" thing. Damn, way to make delete more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: So it's safe to say the answer is, you can't, exactly. It will remove that sequence of chars, but any other instances of those chars as well.

Comment: Nope, there's a question in the title too -- ;)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs:

```
delete([other_str]+) → new_str
```

> Returns a copy of str with all characters in the intersection of its
>   arguments deleted. Uses the same rules for building the set of
>   characters as String#count.

ex:

```
"hello".delete "l","lo"        #=> "heo"
"hello".delete "lo"            #=> "he"
"hello".delete "aeiou", "^e"   #=> "hell"
"hello".delete "ej-m"          #=> "ho"
```

So every character in the intersection of the two strings is removed.